# Transpose rows in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Input is like below -

```
IndexName      ColumnName
Ind1           Col1
Ind1           Col2
Ind2           Col3
```

Now how to generate below output using sql (Oracle 11g) -

```
IndexName      ColumnName
Ind1           ("Col1","Col2")
Ind2           ("Col3")
```

Please note column values of IndexName , ColumnName are not known beforehand.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG`

```
select indexname,     '('||listagg('"' ||columnname||'"' ,',')
   within group ( ORDER BY columnname) ||')' as ColumnName
from t group by indexname
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d242e788a869dd0cb4f27bf278b4c33)